# Does exists other way of indenting ffmpeg batch script?

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg, indentation

How can I indent code in a Batch script other than using temporal variables %= =%?
This is the only code that works for me with indentation.

```
::2020-12-31 10:43:40
@ECHO OFF
::SET VIDEO="E:\Vídeos\test.mp4"
SET VIDEO=%1
SET /P TITULO=Introduzca el título del vídeo: 
ffmpeg ^
    -y ^
    -loglevel verbose ^
    -i %VIDEO% ^
    -vf ^
          scale=^
%=          =%width=-2:^
%=          =%height=360,^
%=      =%drawtext=^
%=          =%fontfile='C\:/Windows/Fonts/impact.ttf':^
%=          =%text=%TITULO%:^
%=          =%fontcolor=white:^
%=          =%borderw=1:^
%=          =%fontsize=18:^
%=          =%alpha=0.99:^
%=          =%x=(w-tw)/2:^
%=          =%y=th/4:^
%=          =%expansion=none,^
%=      =%drawtext=^
%=          =%fontfile='C\:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf':^
%=          =%text='WATERMARK':^
%=          =%fontcolor=white:^
%=          =%borderw=1:^
%=          =%fontsize=18:^
%=          =%alpha=0.60:^
%=          =%x=w-tw-10:^
%=          =%y=h-th-10:^
%=          =%expansion=none^
    -map 0:v ^
    -map 0:a? ^
    -c:v h264 ^
    -crf 30 ^
    -c:a aac ^
    -q:a 1 ^
    -ac 1 ^
    %VIDEO:~0,-5%_WATERMARK.mp4
```

If I try to use spaces or tabs in the "-vf" section ffmpeg interprets them as the end of the filter and the start of the output file argument .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should quote the video-filter expression. Then you don't need those temporal variables:

```
ffmpeg^
  -y^
  -loglevel verbose^
  -i %VIDEO%^
  -vf ^"^
    scale=^
      width=-2:^
      height=360,^
    drawtext=^
      fontfile='C\:/Windows/Fonts/impact.ttf':^
      text='%TITULO%':^
      fontcolor=white:^
      borderw=1:^
      fontsize=18:^
      alpha=0.99:^
      x=(w-tw)/2:^
      y=th/4:^
      expansion=none,^
    drawtext=^
      fontfile='C\:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf':^
      text='WATERMARK':^
      fontcolor=white:^
      borderw=1:^
      fontsize=18:^
      alpha=0.60:^
      x=w-tw-10:^
      y=h-th-10:^
      expansion=none^
  "^
  -map 0:v^
  [...]
```

Yes, that's `^"` at the beginning and `"` at the end.

Also please quote the "TITULO"-variable within the expression: `'%TITULO%'`.

Finally, as a side note; the encoding.
There's a pretty good chance your Batch script is encoded as `ANSI (Windows-1252)`.
This means your `Introduzca el título del vídeo` will come out as `Introduzca el tφtulo del vφdeo`.

The ANSI encoded `í` (ALT+0237) comes out as the OEM encoded `φ` (ALT+237).

In order to get the OEM encoded `í` (ALT+161) you have to enter the ANSI encoded `¡` (ALT+0161).
So `Introduzca el t¡tulo del v¡deo` will come out as `Introduzca el título del vídeo`.

[This website](http://www.irongeek.com/alt-numpad-ascii-key-combos-and-chart.html) has a nice chart where you can look it up, but [`charmap`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_Map_%28Windows%29) can also help.
If you highlight the `í`, then you'll see `U+00ED (0xA1): Latin Small Letter I With Acute      Keystroke: Alt+0237` mentioned below.

`ED` (hex) = `237` (dec) and `A1` (hex) = `161` (dec).

You can ignore this if your Batch script is encoded as `OEM (CP437)`.